# lu decomposition multithreading broke c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a lu decomposition implementation without multithreading, I'm trying to implement this algorithm using standard threads, but it doesn't always work correctly

plain lu decomposition works great, but it's not:

```
#define MAX_THREADS std::thread::hardware_concurrency()

void LUDecompositionMT(std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix){
    int n = matrix.size();

    std::vector<std::vector<double> > lower(n, std::vector<double>(n));
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > upper(n, std::vector<double>(n));
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    upper = matrix;

    for (int c = 0; c < MAX_THREADS; c++) {
        threads.emplace_back(std::thread([=, &lower, &upper] {
            int start = (n * c / MAX_THREADS);
            int end = (n * (c + 1) / MAX_THREADS);

            for (int k = start == 0 ? 1 : start; k < end; k++)
            {
                for (int i = k - 1; i < n; i++)
                    for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
                    {
                        lower[j][i] = upper[j][i] / upper[i][i];
                    }


                for (int i = k; i < n; i++)
                    for (int j = k - 1; j < n; j++)
                    {
                        upper[i][j] = upper[i][j] - lower[i][k - 1] * upper[k - 1][j];

                    }
            }

            }));
    }

    for (auto& t : threads) {
        t.join();
    }
}
```

I have done several tests and they are different. some work correctly (1) and some don't (2-3) **(4 threads are running)**
[image]
[image]
[image]
what's my mistake?

P.S. it is necessary to use standard threads and possibly some synchronization methods (mutex, etc.)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Use parentheses `((n * c) / MAX_THREADS)`.

Comment: Are different threads accessing the same parts of the matrix? It looks like each thread calculates part of lower and then reads from part of lower. Are those the same part or does one thread access parts of lower that a different thread calculates?

Comment: @kiner_shah no difference

Comment: Before doing threads, you should optimize your code on single thread level. For example: using `const &` as argument of function, or implement matrix class instead using vector of vectors.

Comment: @user253751 vertical chunks do not overlap and "adjacent" threads should not be accessed. theoretically, the error can be in the section of the outer loop `for (int k = start == 0 ? 1 : start; k < end; k++)`

Comment: I think that since `i` goes from `k` up to `n`, it also goes above `end`, therefore `lower[i]` accesses parts of the array that would be calculated by other threads, that might not have calculated them yet.

Comment: You clearly have a race condition on `lower` and `upper`. Note that calculation of those depend on previous iteration of threads. It is possible that when one thtread do: `lower[j][i] = upper[j][i] / upper[i][i];` other does `upper[i][j] = upper[i][j] - lower[i][k - 1] * upper[k - 1][j];` for the same values of `i` and `j`.

Comment: @MarekR Maybe I should take a different approach when splitting into threads, so as not to complicate things and not write additional classes?

Comment: First you should focus on single thread optimization. Threads are hard and errors are nondeterministic what makes them even harder. And I see lots of room for singe thread improvement.

Comment: The smallest index you use in each thread is `start-1`, which is the same as `end-1` of a different thread.

Comment: @molbdnilo problem is `i` and `j` for loops which are iterating to `n - 1` value for all threads. So same pairs of `i` and `j` are used by different threads for write and read on `lower` and `upper`.

Answer (score 0):

Each thread reads and writes all over the array (I did not bother to work out the math of LU decomposition) including in the same spots that other threads read from. Depending on whether a thread reads the spot first, or another thread writes it first, the first thread will read a different number.

You need to be careful when splitting a calculation into multiple threads. It's best if each thread only works on one part of the matrix (a so-called *embarrassingly parallel* algorithm), but it's also okay if each thread waits until the other parts that it needs to read have already been calculated. You tried to implement an algorithm where each thread only works on one part of the matrix but you didn't actually make it so each thread only works on one part of the matrix - it reads from other parts.

The amount of multithreading that's *possible* is highly dependent on what you are trying to do. I don't know whether or not it's possible to write a sensible multi-threaded algorithm for LU decomposition, as the algorithms shown on Wikipedia seem to heavily rely on results being calculated in a certain order. Apparently there are *research papers* written about this.